# Getting a `error: unresolved reference` with gradle

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, rome

I am using [rometools](https://github.com/rometools/rome) to parse a RSS feed and when I run the sample code here I get an unresolved error. The project is using Java 11 and Kotlin with gradle 7.1

```
fun parseRSSFeed(feed:String): SyndFeed? {
    val feed = SyndFeedInput().build(XmlReader(URL(feed)))
    println(feed.title)
    return feed
}
```

Error:

```
/Users/simon/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-11.0.11/bin/java -javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 EAP.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=62778:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 EAP.app/Contents/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 EAP.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-compiler.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 EAP.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-reflect.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 EAP.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-stdlib.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 EAP.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-script-runtime.jar org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler -kotlin-home /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2 EAP.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc -script /Users/simon/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.2/scratches/scratch.kts
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil (file:/Applications/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202021.2%20EAP.app/Contents/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/lib/kotlin-compiler.jar) to method java.util.ResourceBundle.setParent(java.util.ResourceBundle)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.intellij.util.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
error: unresolved reference: rometools (scratch.kts:1:12)
error: unresolved reference: rometools (scratch.kts:2:12)
error: unresolved reference: SyndFeedInput (scratch.kts:5:12)
error: unresolved reference: XmlReader (scratch.kts:5:34)
scratch.kts:1:12: error: unresolved reference: rometools
import com.rometools.rome.io.SyndFeedInput
           ^
scratch.kts:2:12: error: unresolved reference: rometools
import com.rometools.rome.io.XmlReader
           ^
scratch.kts:5:12: error: unresolved reference: SyndFeedInput
val feed = SyndFeedInput().build(XmlReader(URL("https://**.org/en/rss/blog.xml")))
           ^
scratch.kts:5:34: error: unresolved reference: XmlReader
val feed = SyndFeedInput().build(XmlReader(URL("https://**.org/en/rss/blog.xml")))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Incorrect** use of `Reflection` in Java/Kotlin.

You are using `Reflection` to parse input `feed`. However, the contents of `feed` contain values undefined in the current Application, thus unable to be processed by `Reflection`.

**To solve this issue**, you have to strictly manage input `feed` so that only defined members could be allowed to be processed by `Reflection`.

PS: If you are unsure of what `Reflection` is, you can easily follow this friendly [tutorial on `Reflection`](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html).

Let me know if you have more questions. Thanks.